# Redirect to a POST action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I have a post action called `Login` which does some server side validation and the actual logging in of the user. I have another post action where the user resets their password. I would like this action to directly log them in upon success, instead of bringing them back to the login back to type in their new credentials.

I would like to somehow call the logic I've already written. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Is this an ajax call?

Comment: No, it's just a normal form post -> controller action -> (hopefully) Login action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just extract the part of your `Login` action that does the actual logging in to another method of your controller? Which could then also be called from your `ResetPassword` action.

```
public class FirstController : BaseLoginController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        base.ExecuteLogin();
    }
}

public class SecondController : BaseLoginController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetPassword()
    {
        base.ExecuteLogin();
    }
}

public class BaseLoginController
{
    protected void ExecuteLogin()
    {
        // login logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I can, but one more problem is that I'm trying to call this action from another controller--I can't do redirects/ViewBag things/TempData things when it's static, and pulling those parts out would basically defeat the point of reusing it (there are around three lines that aren't the mentioned processes). Is it possible to have this work without the static modifier?

Comment: @idlackage you could create some sort of base controller that both controllers inherit of, and have your login method in there. You'll be able to call it from both controllers and nothing has to be static.